# Paypal in a AngularJS and API-REST Silex PHP as Server

Tags: php, angularjs, paypal, silex

First of all, thanks to read and comment.

I have a Front-end application developed in AngularJS and an APIREst server in PHP with Silex Framework.

Now, I would like to add Paypal payment button in one of the pages. I have been reading Paypal documentation and lot of blogs but I can't understand what is the workflow I should follow.

So far, I submit Paypal button calling the URL with a form and all hidden inputs in order to send items, prices and other params as POST method. Paypal is showed properly and the client pay and the process in Paypal is confirmed... but I would like to know, what is the next setp? How I return to my angularjs page? What is the url return I should send in the form? How server knows if  payment is accepted? How the client is redirect? IPN??.. in server, in front-end???

Thanks for help.